# How do I solve the Magic Lantern puzzle in the Boston Underground?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I'm in the Boston underground and just got to a puzzle about the Masons and a Magic Lantern.

There are 4 symbols being projected on a wall: justice, a cross, a globe, and a ship steering wheel. The hint is a lengthy text on the masons.

I just don't get the puzzle. What is the solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I literally just did this!

The clues are in a letter you find, and they are as follows:

```
UNDER ALL CIRCUMSTANCE-OBEY AND BALANCE THE MORAL LAW
THE GLOBE OVER
BE IT CHRISTIANITY OF THE WEST
BUDDHISM OF THE EAST
```

The `BALANCE` is represented by the scales of justice. The globe is the `GLOBE`, obviously. The cross symbolizes `CHRISTIANITY`, and the steering wheel is a symbol for `BUDDHISM`.

Based on the last two lines, Christianity is of the *West*, so **the cross goes on the left**. Buddhism is of the *East*, so **the wheel goes to the right**.

Then, for the first two lines, the moral law is to be obeyed *under* all circumstances, so **the scales are on the bottom**. Furthermore, the moral law must be obeyed all *over* the globe, so **the globe is on top**.

Comment: Yeah, I just contined my research and found it later. Funny thing is, when you read that text in the french version, there's no text in capitals.

Comment: Basically, if you are playing in another language, switch your console to english for this part, or you'll never find the solution to these puzzles by yourself.

Comment: Damn! I'm playing in spanish and these sentences have not directly translated.

Now I understand because this had no sense :)